# OCaml pattern matching on builtin types

Tags: types, pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm trying to write a polymorphic function, which needs to do something slightly different depending on the type of the parameter.  Is there any way that I can do a pattern match on the type of the object, using the builtin types?  I'm thinking of something along these lines:

```
let to_string v =
    match v with
    | string -> v
    | int -> string_of_int v
    | _ -> ""
```

but this doesn't seem to be a valid OCaml program.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633200/determining-type-on-the-fly-in-ocamls-oop-construct), but that doesn't quite answer my question either.  I would *prefer* to use the standard,builtin types rather than constructing new types for this (although I can do that if that is the only way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually that answer completely applies to you. You can only match one type class, and the type defined by the union of `int`, `string`, `float`, ... does not exist, and needs to be created (as in the previous answer). `'a` operates on a particular type, but does not represent a union of all types.

You might be able to do what you want using an external C function ([18.3](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual032.html)), although, glancing at the atomic tags section, I'm not sure you'll be able to differentiate `char` and  `int`.

Comment: :( - that's what I was afraid of. Oh well, I guess my program will just not quite look as nice.

Comment: Why are you trying to do something like this? there probably is a better way.

Comment: I thought that I would be able to write a polymorphic function this way, with overrides for the different types that I need, but thinking it over some more, I will probably need to use variants anyway, since I will end up making a lexing step as well.